# Connect from Google Functions (PY) to MySQL SQL Server

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect from a Google Functions in Python 3.11 to a MySQL instance I have set up.

> @functions_framework.http
> def mysql_engine(request):
> options = request.get_json()
> MYSQL_USER = options['user']
> MYSQL_PASSWORD = options['pass']
> MYSQL_HOST = options['host']
> MYSQL_DB_NAME = options['db_name']
>
> ```
> engine_gam = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
>     'mysql+mysqlconnector://' +
>     MYSQL_USER +
>     ':' +
>     MYSQL_PASSWORD +
>     '@' +
>     MYSQL_HOST +
>     '/' +
>     MYSQL_DB_NAME
> )
> engine_gam.connect()
> ```

However, I am getting the following error.

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError)
> 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x:xxxx' (110 Connection
> timed out) (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)

I know the "easy" solution is to add 0.0.0.0/0 as a whitelist in the SQL Server and it works with this method, however I would like to know if it possible to use a Service Account to work as a whitelist method.

Service account that is being used by Google Function:
[image: Service account that is being used by Google Function]

Same Service account perms in IAM:

[image: Same Service account perms]

This is how I currently have it setup, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For the most basic usecase where you are attempting to connect using a MySQL user and password, try connecting using the built-in Cloud SQL Proxy. Follow these instructions that describe how to configure [unix socket path in Python](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connect_to).

This way you can connect without installing any additional libraries in your application.

```
import os

import sqlalchemy


def connect_unix_socket() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    """Initializes a Unix socket connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of MySQL."""
    # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
    # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
    # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
    # keep secrets safe.
    db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]  # e.g. 'my-database-user'
    db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]  # e.g. 'my-database-password'
    db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]  # e.g. 'my-database'
    unix_socket_path = os.environ[
        "INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET"
    ]  # e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'

    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        # Equivalent URL:
        # mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="mysql+pymysql",
            username=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            database=db_name,
            query={"unix_socket": unix_socket_path},
        ),
        # ...
    )
    return pool
```

However, if you plan to use IAM Authentication or connect to your MySQL instance through a private IP address, you may want to use the library Cloud SQL Connector for Python.

The same document also shows how to connect using [Cloud SQL Connectors from Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connect-connectors)